# How to add Calling and SMS Sending Feature onclick of single button in android?

Tags: android, sms, buttonclick

I want a calling and sms sending onclick of single button. Right now I am able send either sms or call. But I want when user clicks on the button, it should ask for both , Call or SMS. And let the users selects. Phone or SMS. How can I acheive this?

Comment: Its simple on click of button create a custom dialog which shows an option of call and sms

Answer (score 4):

Create alert dialog and show it when user click a button

Try Below code

```
public void popup(final int pos) {
    // load detail view of contacts

    final CharSequence[] items = { "Call", "SMS", "Locate", "View Details" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Action");

    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if (items[item].equals("Call")) {
                // invoke call functionality
                onCall(pos);
            }

            if (items[item].equals("SMS")) {
                // invoke sms functionality
                onSms(pos);
            }



        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

agree with @suresh.

add the following code with his answer.

**inside onCall method code to call**

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);          
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));          
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

**inside onSms method code to sms**

// To start launch the sms activity all you need is this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
```

// You can add extras to populate your own message and such like this

```
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", x); 
//then just startActivity with the intent.

startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your own chooser (a dialog). When the user clicks on the button, you show them your dialog and then he/she can select or phone or sms.